# Quorum -- Is Raft more scalable in terms of TPS compared to Istanbul BFT (IBFT)?

Tags: quorum

This question is on Quorum, the enterprise flavour for Ethereum.

Understand that BFT algorithms are always prepared for the worst possible circumstances and pays a price for this in terms of speed.

Can one reasonably make the statement / assessment that Raft is more scalable in terms of TPS compared to Istanbul BFT (IBFT)?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Raft when byzantine fault tolerance is not a requirement. i.e., under no circumstances there will be a byzantine fault. i.e., no malicious/arbitrary faults -- only crash faults where either a node/participant is alive or down.

Use IBFT when there might be malicious actor/nodes/participants.

Raft Model: Leader, Followers. Random Leader election + Replicated Log. 
IBFT Model: Proposer, Validators. Validators wait for 2F + 1 commits before updating the blockchain.